# How to resize a Bitmap without it being pixelated

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I found a method that resizes an image's aspect ratio and displays it in an `ImageView` and it looks just fine with code that looks like this:

```
    int new_width = (int) Math.floor((double) bWidth * (double) sHeight
            / (double) bHeight);
    params.width = new_width;
    params.height = sHeight;

    fullImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Where `sHeight` is the height of the device's screen. However I want to carry out this action in a `Service` and then setting the image as the background which means I created my own `ImageView` through the Java code and performed the actions above. It keeps coming out pixelated  no matter what code I use. Any suggestions? I have also tried [this code](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/) but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It is not about code but graphics things. Any small picture who's enlarged will have a quality loss if it is not a SVG one.

Use a bigger picture as a background and reduce his size to keep image quality.

Comment: the same image is used in the activity's image view and it is not pixelated shows up just right and can be used to set the wallpaper without quality loss but when done from a service there is quality loss

Comment: Ok Manny264 I will have a deeper look at it tomorrow and I'll come back to you

Comment: actually I was using Picasa so in the request I was able to request a bigger size of the photo and then try to resize that one and that worked